# Read text, calculate word length and tally like occurrences

Tags: javascript, html

### Goal:

Write a JavaScript that reads several lines of text and print a table indicating number of one-letter words, two-letter words, etc.appearing in the text.

This is my code to reads several lines of text and prints a table indicating the number of one-letter words, two-letter words, three-letter words, etc. appearing in the text. For example, the phrase; `Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer`.

The output will be:

```
Word length  Occurrences
1              0
2              2
3              1
4              2 (including 'tis)
5              0
6              2
7              1
```

But I do not get any output..So I need help. This is what I currently have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>
Assignment 1
</title>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<b>Assignment1  <br> <br>
Name: Omnia Hassan Elshaer  <br> <br>
Current Date: <b>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

// the current date.
var currentDate = new Date()
var day = currentDate.getDate()
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
document.write("<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>")

// function to calculate number of occurrences.
function search()
{
var str = document.getElementById("string").value;

var c = new Array();

c=str.split(" ");

var count = new Array(15);

for(var i=0;i<count.length;i++){

 count[i]=0;
}

var wordlenght;

for(var j=0;j<c.length;j++){
wordlenght=c[i].length;
count[wordlenght]++;

}

var content= "<table>"+"<thead><th>Word length</th><th>Occurrences</th></thead><tbody>";

 for(var m=0;m<count.length;m++){

 content+="<tr><td>"+m+"</td><td>"+count[m]+"</td></tr>";

 }
 content+="</tbody></table>";
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = content;

//output(count);

}
/*function output(count){

 var content= "<table>"+"<thead><th>Word length</th><th>Occurrences</th></thead><tbody>";

 for(var m=0;m<count.length;m++){

 content+="<tr><td>"+m+"</td><td>"+count[m]+"</td></tr>";

 }
 content+="</tbody></table>";
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = content;
}*/


</script>
 <br> <br>

<label><b> Enter the string to determine the number of occurrences :<b>
<input name = "string" type = "text" /> </label> <br> <br>

<input type = "button" value = "Result" text="Result" onclick ="search()"/> <br> <br> 

<div id="result"> </div> 


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const sentence = "Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer"

// get an array with the length of each word
lengths = sentence.split(" ")
  .map(word => word.length)

// get the longest word, e.g. "7"
const max = Math.max(...lengths)

// make a sequence from 0 to the longest word: 0,1,...,7
counts = [...Array(max).keys()].map(n => {
  // check how often the number occurs in the 'lengths' array
  return lengths.filter(x => x === n + 1).length
})

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = counts.map((count, i) => {
  return `<tr><td>${i+1}</td><td>${count}</td></tr>`
}).join('')
```

```html
<table id="results"></table>
```

Comment: it is work perfect .. but there is some codes i can't understand it

Comment: I added some comments to explain the steps - hope that helps.